# C# How can I add to list with a button?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, button

I have a method in C# that i will post in below code. In this method I made a list and used it for calculation. But the user wanted to add dates to that list. So I made a quick panel to add to list. I added one `DateTimePicker` and one `Button`, but when I want to add to that list with a button, the code gives me this error:

> The name holidays does not exist in the current content

How can I access my list within a button and add to it?

This is where I keep the list for calculation:

```
public void TatilHesap()
{
    var holidays = new List<Holiday>();
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(1, 1));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(04, 23));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 01));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 19));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(07, 15));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(08, 30));
    holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(10, 29));
    holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 23)));
    holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 24)));
    holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 25)));
    holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 26)));
}
```

And this is my button:

```
private void BtnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: You should declare `holidays` as a field: `private List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract `holidays` as a *field*:

```
    private List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>();         

    public void TatilHesap()
    {
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(1, 1));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(04, 23));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 01));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 19));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(07, 15));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(08, 30));
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(10, 29));
        holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 23)));
        holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 24)));
        holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 25)));
        holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 26)));
    }

    private void BtnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // now user can add an item into holidays
        //TODO: put relevant code here
        holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(1, 7)); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! And i have 1 more relevant question. Are those items that i added to my list saved? Or are they temporary like when i close the program will they be gone?

Comment: @Mert: they are temporary, they will be gone when you close the program; you can *save* `holidays` items into a file or a database

Comment: And would i be able to use these dates like i did before? When i save them in database i mean. Because when calculatingi i check for dates i do: `if (holidays.contains...)`

Comment: @Mert: on the program start you should *load* the items from database and you'll be able to check as `holidays.Contains...`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read about variable scopes and lots of OOPS.

```
public void TatilHesap()
        {
            //below is Local Variable 
            var holidays = new List<Holiday>();
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(1, 1));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(04, 23));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 01));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(05, 19));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(07, 15));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(08, 30));
            holidays.Add(new MonthDayBasedHoliday(10, 29));
            holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 23)));
            holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 24)));
            holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 25)));
            holidays.Add(new FixedDateBasedHoliday(new DateTime(2020, 05, 26)));
        }
```

As a quick Fix... move that Variable to Class Level and you can access it in all Functions and Event Handlers.

But, not at all a good OO design for software.